# Showing that Möbius band can't retract onto the boundary circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Trying to prove that Möbius band can't retract onto the boundary circle, I got an idea that I must show the below thing.

If $\alpha\in\pi_1 (\partial M)$  is a generator, its image $i^*(\alpha) \in \pi_ 1 (M)$  under the inclusion $i:\partial M\to M$  is the square of an element of $\pi_1 (M)$.

I can visualize such phenomenon in my head, but can't formulate an argument using explicit homotopies and paths. Could anyone suggest me how to rigorously prove the above fact?